# OpenOffice Calc function return #VALUE

Tags: openoffice-calc, openoffice-basic

I would like to write a Basic function for Calc that return #VALUE! testable with ISERR().

```
Function foo()
    foo = #VALUE!
End Function
```

But that foo function return 0 and not some error #VALUE!. How should I do it?

Comment: You can create (and return) an error object using the [CVErr() function](http://cereusapis.com/iserror-cverr-openoffice-basic/) in StarBasic. But sadly, neither ISERR() nor ISERROR() detect the result as error, both returning FALSE instead. Even using the [error code 519 for #VALUE! (with CVErr(519)](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Calc_Error_Codes) helps... :-(

Comment: @tohuwawohu: Yes, I tried returning 519 as well but it did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `#VALUE!` is only shown when there is a calculation error in the spreadsheet.  So it is not possible to return such an error.

Instead, cause a `#VALUE!` error by returning text when a number is expected:

```vb
Function get_number() As Any
    'get_number = 0  'This line will not cause an error.
    get_number = ""  'This line will cause #VALUE! because it is not a number.
End Function
```

Set the formula to `=ISERR(GET_NUMBER() + 0)`.

See https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?t=44830.

Comment: That's the answer I found before coming here hoping for THE answer. That's really a pity that we need to hack something like that :(